# Incorrect legend labeling when using multiple geoms from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using two `geom`s from ggplot, `geom_point` and `geom_boxplot`, to create the plot shown below. Note that the legend for the points from `geom_point` is incorrect, since the points are being treated as boxplots (in the legend, anything that has the string "TSS filtered" appended at the end is supposed to be a point instead of a boxplot). I'm not exactly sure how to fix this.

I've included the output from `dput` for `df` (which has the data for the points) and and an abbreviated output from `dput` for `correlations_long` with only `Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte` at the end of this post (`correlations_long` has the data for the boxplots).

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=df, aes(x=factor(name, levels=unique(name)), 
                   y=value, color=cell_type), size=3) +
    geom_boxplot(data=correlations_long,
                 aes(x=factor(num_fragments, levels=unique(num_fragments)), 
                     y=correlation, color=cell_type)) +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, angle=90)) +
    xlab("Num Fragments") +
    ylab("Correlation") +
    labs(color="Cell type") + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits = as.factor(sort(as.integer(
                     unique(correlations_long["num_fragments"]) %>% pull))))
```

[image]

dput output for `df`:

```
structure(list(name = c("1000", "2983", "8901", "26558", "79237", 
"236409", "705340", "2104417", "1000", "2983", "8901", "26558", 
"79237", "236409", "705340", "2104417", "1000", "2983", "8901", 
"26558", "79237", "236409", "705340", "1000", "2983", "8901", 
"26558", "79237", "236409", "705340"), value = c(-0.217233727868593, 
-0.313682277356269, -0.443536645598551, -0.521959275706954, -0.554173539213182, 
-0.568676467365853, -0.570234215267721, -0.568882712628573, -0.245220070304608, 
-0.340830882171965, -0.464351593030875, -0.514900990218652, -0.576472067464575, 
-0.59987452898425, -0.58002528101756, NA, -0.202054800162606, 
-0.272836084111954, -0.410191142797998, -0.477791235306681, -0.529504522998714, 
-0.544302595354142, -0.547864149527051, -0.203245452534301, -0.317663927450409, 
-0.463555979106284, -0.531779779812837, -0.584611371556314, -0.596363138503893, 
-0.603323902370038), cell_type = c("Skin Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", 
"Skin Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", "Skin Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", 
"Skin Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", "Skin Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", 
"Skin Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", "Skin Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", 
"Skin Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", "Skin Melanocyte TSS filtered", 
"Skin Melanocyte TSS filtered", "Skin Melanocyte TSS filtered", 
"Skin Melanocyte TSS filtered", "Skin Melanocyte TSS filtered", 
"Skin Melanocyte TSS filtered", "Skin Melanocyte TSS filtered", 
"Skin Melanocyte TSS filtered", "Skin Sun Exposed Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", "Skin Sun Exposed Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", "Skin Sun Exposed Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", "Skin Sun Exposed Fibroblast (Epithelial) TSS filtered", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte TSS filtered", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte TSS filtered", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte TSS filtered", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte TSS filtered", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte TSS filtered", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte TSS filtered", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte TSS filtered")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

dput output for `correlations_long`:

```
structure(list(num_fragments = c("1000", "2983", "8901", "26558", 
"79237", "236409", "705340", "2104417", "1000", "2983", "8901", 
"26558", "79237", "236409", "705340", "2104417", "1000", "2983", 
"8901", "26558", "79237", "236409", "705340", "2104417", "1000", 
"2983", "8901", "26558", "79237", "236409", "705340", "2104417", 
"1000", "2983", "8901", "26558", "79237", "236409", "705340", 
"2104417", "1000", "2983", "8901", "26558", "79237", "236409", 
"705340", "2104417", "1000", "2983", "8901", "26558", "79237", 
"236409", "705340", "2104417", "1000", "2983", "8901", "26558", 
"79237", "236409", "705340", "2104417", "1000", "2983", "8901", 
"26558", "79237", "236409", "705340", "2104417", "1000", "2983", 
"8901", "26558", "79237", "236409", "705340", "2104417"), correlation = c(-0.142552912633417, 
-0.282063642684633, -0.358365031342374, -0.476429739615196, -0.537715257634154, 
-0.556507228835608, -0.569290141585588, -0.572632853618199, -0.176729246694482, 
-0.24002202483771, -0.364372461559598, -0.472537637457574, -0.521181023255881, 
-0.55984376716404, -0.568700874753408, -0.571018314483162, -0.140246012715342, 
-0.265674247705073, -0.375020572402195, -0.466325284307382, -0.543448139139435, 
-0.554991371026006, -0.567841698567904, -0.572626483191379, -0.1626413145619, 
-0.243304716053789, -0.371378032491436, -0.483941606311232, -0.530845237866024, 
-0.554468643820047, -0.568143694079138, -0.570862620697964, -0.116564401636032, 
-0.255281310962979, -0.377464344414864, -0.48674764840038, -0.534623306115981, 
-0.559268330681496, -0.568358687051924, -0.572804016053457, -0.150598835600339, 
-0.250340179755359, -0.378018309624652, -0.483361453380124, -0.539940888020042, 
-0.550240697380326, -0.568095658044177, -0.571273467002167, -0.140801591191654, 
-0.243907992257946, -0.365389408139248, -0.466829280870502, -0.53860508515168, 
-0.554893906404059, -0.567088355995875, -0.571123984164459, -0.175643182028142, 
-0.257385314673002, -0.354177687837023, -0.494490415619058, -0.528805416429225, 
-0.556373311038017, -0.569306986486968, -0.572012337412355, -0.171542682526591, 
-0.246289070052161, -0.366099952822677, -0.453690709343421, -0.530025481091536, 
-0.551777830306486, -0.568937084190358, -0.570650095061955, -0.146629007977338, 
-0.257264392122815, -0.36851473188057, -0.495616527451394, -0.536316439462659, 
-0.557762199945624, -0.569946797833086, -0.57003184524515), cell_type = c("Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", "Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte", 
"Skin Sun Exposed Melanocyte")), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few options. One way is to specify which key glyph to use depending on the color (i.e. if it's red, yellow, green or purple use a dot symbol, and if it's blue use a boxplot symbol; https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/draw_key.html), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# To get the hex codes for the default ggplot2 colorscheme:
# scales::show_col(scales::hue_pal()(5))
# [1] "#F8766D" "#A3A500" "#00BF7D" "#00B0F6" "#E76BF3"

# Create a custom key_glyph function:
draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (data$colour %in% c("#F8766D", "#A3A500", "#00BF7D", "#E76BF3")) {
    draw_key_point(data, params, size)
  } else if (data$colour == "#00B0F6") {
    draw_key_boxplot(data, params, size)
  } else {
    draw_key_point(data, params, size)
  }
}

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=factor(name, levels=unique(name)), 
                          y=value, color=cell_type), size=3) +
  geom_boxplot(data=correlations_long,
               aes(x=factor(num_fragments, levels=unique(num_fragments)), 
                   y=correlation, color=cell_type),
               key_glyph = "cust") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, angle=90)) +
  xlab("Num Fragments") +
  ylab("Correlation") +
  labs(color="Cell type") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = as.factor(sort(as.integer(
    unique(correlations_long["num_fragments"]) %>% pull))))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

---

Another way is to split up the legend into two (i.e. one for color, one for fill) and this specifies the symbols accordingly:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=factor(name, levels=unique(name)), 
                          y=value, fill=cell_type), shape = 21, size=3) +
  geom_boxplot(data=correlations_long,
               aes(x=factor(num_fragments, levels=unique(num_fragments)), 
                   y=correlation, color=cell_type)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, angle=90)) +
  xlab("Num Fragments") +
  ylab("Correlation") +
  labs(color="Cell type", fill = "Cell type") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = as.factor(sort(as.integer(
    unique(correlations_long["num_fragments"]) %>% pull))))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

---

Or, you can stick with the combined legend and combine the key glyphs (i.e. a boxplot and a dot for each):

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=correlations_long,
               aes(x=factor(num_fragments, levels=unique(num_fragments)), 
                   y=correlation, color=cell_type),
               key_glyph = "boxplot") +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=factor(name, levels=unique(name)), 
                          y=value, color=cell_type), size=3,
             key_glyph = "point") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, angle=90)) +
  xlab("Num Fragments") +
  ylab("Correlation") +
  labs(color="Cell type", fill = "Cell type") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = as.factor(sort(as.integer(
    unique(correlations_long["num_fragments"]) %>% pull))))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In my opinion the first option is the best, but it's also the most complicated; if you need help implementing it, edit your question then tag me in a comment and I'll help you troubleshoot.

Comment: decided to go with option 2 because I have to do this for multiple types of tissue (in this case it was Skin) so option 1 would be tedious. Thanks a lot!